# Rails without actionmailbox and actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to use Rails (7) without actionmailer and actionmailbox? I replaced  the `require "rails/all"` with a small selection of gems I want to use. `action_mailer/railtie` and `action_mailbox/engine` is commented out. My Gemfile only contains the `rails` gem and some other unrelevant gems. But when I see the resulting Gemfile.lock after a `bundle install`, actionmailer and actionmailbox (and others) are still there:

[image]

Is there a way so exclude this from the resulting Gemfile.lock? I don't want this in my production deployment.

Comment: it's a `rails` gem dependency. `require` doesn't affect the Gemfile. you have to split `gem "rails"` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/rails.gemspec#L41.

Comment: Is there no way to tell bundler to _not_ download/include/use the dependency? Like a blacklist/ignore list?

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What is the reason you don't want these gems?

Comment: @Schwern: I want my resulting deployment footprint as small and clean as possible, because I do not need any mail stuff, test framework, rake and others in my production docker image when I do not use it anyway. So the question is clear: How to blacklist/ignore certain gems when generating the Gemfile.lock, even if it comes as a dependency of another package?

Comment: @f00860 I see what you're going for, but cutting out gem dependencies is not clean. Micro-optimizing installed gems is not necessary in most cases; it adds maintenance hassle and possibly breaks gems. It doesn't gain you anything but perhaps a tiny bit of disk space; disk is cheap. Do you believe these gems will cause problems in production?

Comment: @f00860 Note that `rails-dom-testing` is needed by other components. `rake` is an integral part of Ruby and Rails, you won't get far without it. The remaining optional mail and net- gems are 4M of disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roadmap for such a feature does not look good https://github.com/wycats/bundler/issues/143.

Since you can use each of rails gems independently and they declare their own dependencies, declaring what you need in the Gemfile should be ok.

```
# Gemfile

# gem "rails", "~> 7.0.2.3"

rails_version = "~> 7.0.2.3"
gem "activesupport", rails_version
gem "actionpack",    rails_version
gem "actionview",    rails_version
gem "activemodel",   rails_version
gem "activerecord",  rails_version
# gem "actionmailer",  rails_version
gem "activejob",     rails_version
gem "actioncable",   rails_version
gem "activestorage", rails_version
# gem "actionmailbox", rails_version
gem "actiontext",    rails_version
gem "railties",      rails_version

# ...
```