# How to not require "rails/all"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, memory, benchmarking

```rb
> CUT_OFF=10 bundle exec derailed bundle:mem
TOP: 129.6563 MiB
  rails/all: 58.1406 MiB
    action_mailbox/engine: 32.1719 MiB
```

I would like to not require action_mailbox/engine but it's required by rails/all

I'm not sure which gem it is.

I tried:

```rb
def require(file)
  puts "#{file} => #{caller.first}"
  super
end
```

But nothing shows up

Comment: most likely you have `gem "rails"` (as you should for a rails application). That being said this does not mean you are requiring `action_mailbox/engine` it just means if you do that is how much would be consumed. You can check "config/application.rb" to see what rails libraries you might be requiring

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71993557/207090. `bundle:mem` only looks at your Gemfile, not your app, and it has a special case for [rails](https://github.com/zombocom/derailed_benchmarks/blob/v2.1.2/bin/derailed#L90).

Comment: @Alex you found it thanks! care to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @engineersmnky I actually removed the require for action mailbox so I thought it would disappear from `bundle:mem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was weird that just by looking at *Gemfile* `rails/all` somehow was getting loaded. Sometimes just searching helps:

```bash
$ ag "rails/all" `bundle show --paths`
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/derailed_benchmarks-2.1.2/bin/derailed
90:          require 'rails/all'

# ... 2 more results from `.tt` files
```

---

To answer your question, you can split `rails` gem and use what you need. I've answered that before:
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/71993557/207090*

Now in `config/application.rb` you can replace:

```rb
require "rails/all"
```

with requires in *all.rb* from `railties` gem and remove what you don't need:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4/railties/lib/rails/all.rb*

you don't really have to, since missing files get rescued and app will boot with no issues. Any references/configs for mailbox have to be removed.

```rb
# config/application.rb

# require "rails/all"
require "rails"
%w(
  active_record/railtie
  active_storage/engine
  action_controller/railtie
  action_view/railtie
  active_job/railtie
  action_cable/engine
  action_text/engine
  rails/test_unit/railtie
).each do |railtie|
  # action_mailer/railtie
  # action_mailbox/engine
  begin
    require railtie
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```

Comment: didn't know either about `bundle show --paths`